# how to break page while taking print out in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm printing the postal addresses using `ng-repeat` directive. on the click of "print" button, i wanted to break the page after every 24 li. I want 24 li per page while taking the print out using `angularjs`. I have tried the following link:https://dzone.com/articles/advanced-css-printing-using-css-page-breaks but not found any solution.

Here's my html page -

```
<section class="page-content">
    <div class="page-content-inner">
        <!-- Dashboard -->
        <div class="dashboard-container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-with-borders m-b-0">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="nav-tabs-horizontal margin-bottom-5">
                                <!-- <div align="right">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">                               
                                            <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary-outline margin-inline" type="button" data-target="#myModalregistration" data-toggle="modal" id="addressograph"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="clearvalues()"></i>Add Addressograph</button>
                                        </div>
                                </div> -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="addressograph-container container-example1 ">
                                <div class="table_dis" id="fixedheader">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <li class="" ng-repeat="data in addresograph_listing" style="display: inline-block;width:25%;vertical-align: top;">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 border_2">
                                                <p class="addressograph_name">
                                                    {{data.firstname}} {{data.middle_name}} {{data.sirname}}
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <span class="addressograph_address">
                                                        {{data.address_part_1}}
                                                    </span>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <span class="addressograph_address">
                                                        {{data.address_part_2}}
                                                    </span>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <span class="addressograph_address">
                                                        {{ data.address_part_3}}
                                                    </span>
                                                    <br/>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 print_btn">
                                    <center>
                                        <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary-outline margin-inline " id="printbtn" onclick="myFunction()" type="button">
                                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-print" ng-click="clearvalues()" ng-show="btnsave"></i>Print
                                        </button>
                                    </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```css
@media all 
{ 
    .page-break { display:none; } 
} 
 
@media print 
{ 
    .page-break { display:block; page-break-before:always; } 
}
```

```html
   <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <div>{{item}}</div>
     <div class="page-break;" ng-if="$index % 24 == 0"></div>
    </div>
```

See also a sample https://jsfiddle.net/3jwvqncg/

Comment: Can you be more specific? I added a jsfiddle with example that works

Comment: i have tried your code...web page should display 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 but when i click on "print" button ....print preview should be like page 1 contains 1 2 3, page 2 contains 4 5 6, page 3 conatins 7 8 like

Comment: <style type="text/css"> @media print { body * {visibility: hidden; }#section-to-print, #section-to-print * {visibility: visible;}#section-to-print {position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;}}@media print {div:nth-child(4n):after {page-break-before:always;/*content: '<div class="page-break" ></div>';white-space: pre;*/}}</style>
<div id="section-to-print"><div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div>{{item}}</div><!--   <div class="page-break" ></div>-->
        <!--<div class="page-break;" ng-if="($index) % 3 == 0"></div>-->
    </div></div><button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>